# Call function for both min and max in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, max, min

I have to write a program where I input the number of participants and then the name, surname, age, heigh and weight.

Restrictions- number of participants must be between 1-30

The under age(<18 years) and the ones with height <140cm and >220cm must be eliminated from the list(array).

Finally I have to display the name and weight of the thinest and fatest participants.
I got stuck at writing the min/max function to find out the thinest and fatest from my array. I get the same result for both min and max and I don't actually know how to display the name for them.

Here's my code so far. Can somebody help? I already spent multiple hours playing with the code to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int N;

void remove_persons(string name[], string surname[], float weight[], float height[], float age[])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (age[i] < 18 || height[i] < 140 || height[i] > 220)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < N - 1; j++)
            {
                name[j] = name[j + 1];
                surname[j] = surname[j + 1];
                age[j] = age[j + 1];
                height[j] = height[j + 1];
                weight[j] = weight[j + 1];
            }
            N--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}

float fatfunc(string name[], string surname[], float weight[])
{

    float fat = weight[0];
    int index_fat = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {

        if (weight[i] > fat)
        {
            fat = weight[i];
            index_fat = i;
        }
    }

    return index_fat;
}

float thinfunc(string name[], string surname[], float weight[])
{

    float thin = weight[0];
    int index_thin = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {

        if (weight[i] < thin)
        {
            thin = weight[i];
            index_thin = i;
        }
    }

    return index_thin;
}

int main()
{

    string name[99];
    string surname[99];
    float weight[99];
    float height[99];
    float age[99];
    int fat, thin;

    do
    {
        cout << "Nr. of participants 1-30: ";
        cin >> N;
    } while (N <= 0 || N >= 30);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "Surname[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> surname[i];
        do
        {
            cout << "Age[" << i << "] (>18 years): ";
            cin >> age[i];
        } while (age[i] <= 18);

        cout << "Height in cm [" << i << "] (>140 & <220 cm): ";
        cin >> height[i];

        cout << "Weight [" << i << "]): ";
        cin >> weight[i];
    }

    remove_persons(name, surname, age, weight, height);

    thin = thinfunc(name, surname, weight);
    cout << endl;
    cout << surname[thin] << " " + name[thin] << " is the thinest with a weight of " << weight[thin] << endl;

    fat = fatfunc(name, surname, weight);
    cout << endl;
    cout << surname[fat] << " " + name[fat] << " is the fatest with a weight of " << weight[fat] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are  you using string arrays there?? Looks like you should start with a `struct Person` and have an array of this one.

Comment: A structure, vectors of the structure. and [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)?

Comment: String just for name and surname, for the rest (weight, height, age) they are float

Comment: Alternatively, just don't add persons with invalid data to the vector. This is of course ***much*** simpler if you have a structure for the "person" data that you can read without needing to put it into arrays or vectors.

Comment: [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) may be useful to not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Have a look at std::vector<std::string> and STL algorithm std::remove_if, as @TedLyngmo said no need to reinvent the wheel, [STL containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [STL algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) have been tested and are there for you to be used

Comment: In addition to being extremely overcomplicated (see other comments), `remove_persons` runs in O(n^2), which would kill performance already for not so big `N`, while the function should run in O(n).

Comment: I did an edit on my code by spliting in 2 functions to return the index of the thin(min) and fat(max). The problem is when I call them I get the same result for both of them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SilviuStroe *I already spent multiple hours playing with the code to no avail.* -- Using `std::minmax_element` would solve all of the problems you're having getting the thinnest and fattest.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would be grateful if you showed me how to do it. I'm looking at the documentation but I'm struggling with the code. I need to implement that min/max into a single function.

Comment: @Mughees Thank you! Now I understand why I was getting the same value.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated you can use [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) for finding both the minimum and maximum elements in a container.

Below is a small example of how to use [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). Note that this free function returns a `std::pair` containing 2 iterators. The first iterator points to the element in the container with the smallest value and the second iterator points to the element in the container with the largest value.

I used [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to bind the first iterator to `lightest` and the second iterator to `heaviest`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<float> weights{120, 500, 92.4, 162, 172.3, 99.23};
    // Note that lightest and heaviest are iterators where the lightest iterator
    // points to the the smallest element in the vector and the
    // heaviest iterator points to the largest element in the vector.
    const auto [lightest, heaviest] = std::minmax_element(
        weights.begin(), weights.end());

    std::cout << "Lightest: " << *lightest << " Heaviest: " << *heaviest << '\n';
}
```

And if you're dead set on not using standard containers (which isn't wise in my honest opinion), here is how you can use [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) with `C` style `arrays`.

```
int main() 
{
    float weights[]{120, 500, 92.4f, 162, 172.3f, 99.23f};
    const auto [lightest, heaviest] = std::minmax_element(
        weights, std::end(weights));
    
    std::cout << "Lightest: " << *lightest << " Heaviest: " << *heaviest << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Right, forgot about that overload. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but in C++20 you can use a totally different approach. You don't have to remove anything from your input array (vector), you just skip over unwanted items in a range based for loop with filters.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

struct person_t
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int age;
    double height;
};

// a predicate operating on a person and returning a boolean
// this can later be used in a filter in a range based for loop
bool valid_height(const person_t& person)
{
    return (person.height >= 1.4) && (person.height <= 2.2);
} 

bool valid_age(const person_t& person)
{
    return person.age >= 18;
}

// overload to output a person, makes code more readable later
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const person_t& person)
{
    os << std::format("person : [name = {0}, age = {1}, height = {2}]\n", person.name, person.age, person.height);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    // Create an "array" with 3 persons
    std::vector<person_t> persons{ {"Alice", 20, 1.78}, {"Bob", 4, 78.5}, {"Charlie", 19, 2.4 } };

    // loop only over those persons that meet a criterion
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view
    // and pick up to 30 matching persons
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view
    for (const auto& person : persons 
                            | std::views::filter(valid_height)
                            | std::views::filter(valid_age)
                            | std::views::take(30))
    {
        std::cout << person;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `persons | std::views::filter(valid_height) | std::views::filter(valid_age) | std::views::take(30)` - and you don't have to do any counting.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks Ted, that's much better (didn't spot the take function before)

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I edited it into the answer too ::)

Comment: No not at all, an improvement is an improvement :) Happy  to show that C++ is still evolving to better abstractions

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st problem writing min max function:
answer: you passed the wrong values for remove_person function
you did like this //remove_persons(name, surname, age, weight, height);
it should be like this  // remove_persons(name, surname, weight, height,age);
and for your other problem with displaying names code is here(I mentioned where correction has been done):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int N;
void remove_persons(string name[], string surname[], float weight[], float height[], float age[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (age[i] < 18 || height[i] < 140 || height[i] > 220)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < N - 1; j++)
            {
                name[j] = name[j + 1];
                surname[j] = surname[j + 1];
                age[j] = age[j + 1];
                height[j] = height[j + 1];
                weight[j] = weight[j + 1];
            }
            N--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}

//correction
void fat_and_thin(string name[], string surname[], float weight[])
{
    int fat, thin;
    fat = thin = weight[0];

    //correction
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (weight[i] < thin)
        {
            thin = weight[i];
            j = i;
        }

        if (weight[i] > fat)
        {
            fat = weight[i];
            k = i;
        }
    }

    //correction
    cout <<name[j]<<surname[j]<<" is The thinest has : " << thin << endl;
    cout << name[k] << surname[k] << " is The fatest has : " << fat <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    string name[99];
    string surname[99];
    float weight[99];
    float height[99];
    float age[99];

    do
    {
        cout << "Nr. of participants 1-30: ";
        cin >> N;
    } while (N <= 0 || N >= 30);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "Surname[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> surname[i];
        do
        {
            cout << "Age[" << i << "] (>18 years): ";
            cin >> age[i];
        } while (age[i] <= 18);

        cout << "Height in cm [" << i << "] (>140 & <220 cm): ";
        cin >> height[i];

        cout << "Weight [" << i << "]): ";
        cin >> weight[i];
    }

    //correction
    remove_persons(name, surname, weight, height,age);
    fat_and_thin(name, surname, weight);

    return 0;
}
```